# Country Hopping and Visas

Tags: visas, passports, mexico

I haven't travelled in awhile and not sure what the laws are currently.

So, basically I will have Spring semester off in 2016 and want to bounce around a bit and do some site seeing and hiking.

I have both a US and Brazilian passport. I would like to go to Mexico to visit the Mayan Pyramids and then to Mexico City.

From Mexico City, I am not sure but I am thinking Europe and Asia.

Visa requirements for most countries seem pretty lax with a US Passport but is it possible to just decide my next stop depending on how I feel at the moment? Do I have to make my preparations in advance if there isn't a strict visa requirement?

Comment: Welcome! You're quite new, so please have a read of the [help] as asking multiple questions and for recommendations is generally off topic here and likely to get your question closed. I'd recommend editing your question to single, objectively answerable problems. Hope that helps!

Comment: lol... ok. I'll take the Mexico City Travel Agency question out and put it on another. The other two questions are directly related, it would seem odd to ask them on a seperate question without reposting an almost identical post.

Comment: yeah, I get that.  I just saw the last sentence especially which I knew might attract close votes, and wanted to warn you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at Wikipedia ([US passport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_United_States_citizens)/[Brazilian passport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Brazilian_citizens)). The color codes are a bit different depending on the map but everything in dark green is definitely OK to just drop by and by combining both passports, that includes the Schengen area and most of Europe, most of South-East Asia, Japan, Korea…

Yellow (“visa on arrival”) means you will have to pay some money but can still drop by without advance notice. India or Australia require some form of prior authorization but it can be done online in a matter of hours so you can still more-or-less decide to go there on the spur of the moment. Obviously, some countries like China still require a proper visa so you cannot go there without some preparation.

The Brazilian passport is actually not bad and nicely complements the US passport. It affords you even broader access to South America and a few things people from the US and most of Europe do not have: visa-free access to Russia and visa-on-arrival in Iran. Also visa-free access to Turkey (even if the Turkish e-visa really isn't much of a hassle, that's even better).

One thing to note is that when using visa-free or visa-on-arrival facilities, it's often required to be able to present a ticket *out of the country* on entry (and even when that's not strictly speaking required, it might come in handy). So you do need to either purchase some cheap/refundable ticket you feel comfortable dropping if needed or to plan one move ahead (look up “onward travel” in the archive for more details and country-by-country advice).

Comment: Oh cool. I didn't know Wikipedia had that. Yeah, I guess I will have to make some preparations. It's just weird how the EU is set up. So that is really what throws me off. Flying into Spain and then trams across Europe. I guess I need to buy train tickets in advance. Asia I will do more research on. Awesome answer though. Thanks.

Comment: @David Actually it matters more in South America (at least for Europeans) than in the EU. In the Schengen area, they like to see a ticket out of the area but that's not a strict requirement and I am not even sure they routinely ask US or Brazilian citizens. You can certainly travel within the area without preparation. You might want to buy some tickets in advance, though, but only because that's cheaper ;)